# Array Function on Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to do conditional Standard Deviation on Excel but none of the options Excel gives me seems to be working. I need to to get the standart deviation from a serie, but leaving out numbers higher than an especific value.
I checked another post and they gave a sugestion using array (Crtl+Shift+Enter) but in my formula it seems to not be working. Here is the formula:

`=STDEV(IF((INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("result_chuvas_C_0",$B3,"!$B:$B")))<L3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("result_chuvas_C_0",$B3,"!$B:$B"))))`

[image: Here's an image of my file]

I need to calculate this for several lines, in which there's a code (colum B) and each code represents a different table in this same workbook (you can see it down in the pic), each table has a set of data like [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwxQM.png). If just go to one of these tables as in the table in [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwxQM.png), and try this formula `=STDEV(IF(B2:B79 < C3,B2:B79))` it works and return the right result (20.52). But when I set the array (Crtl+Shift+Enter) for the big formula in the main table it returns an wrong result (0.73) (colum N).

[Here is the data from table result_chuvas_C_02349033](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TP4dHcL6NMI-yNg6JzGirutPckVYAHBaDtwnFExSavY/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take that formula apart. Does the Concatenate() create the expected text string? Does the Indirect() generate the expected range? Does the IF() statement (array entered) create the expected range? Check all these individually, and then wrap the StDev() around it.

Comment: It does! all the colums around are working in basically the same structure, with AVARAGE IF instead of StDev, for example. As I don't need array for avarage, it works fine.

Comment: OK, then step through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool. Where does it break?

Comment: that's the thing, it does not break, there's no error,  it just gives me an wrong result which is 0.73, the right one should be 20.52

Comment: I think I've found where the problem is, i'm using the whole colum B as my reference (B:B), usually the StDev() would ignore all the empty cells that comes in the rows bellow my data. When I set the array it does not ignorem them anymore and uses a lot of empty cells as zeros to calculate de Standert Deviation. I coundn't come up with a solution tho

Comment: I've found a solution, thanks again!